# error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools" while building cython

Tags: python, visual-studio, cython

Compiling setup results in this output:

```
Compiling GetAudioSamples.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing GetAudioSamples.pyx
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\amran\Desktop\Projects\Code\GetAudioSamples\GetAudioSamples.pyx
  tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
running build_ext
building 'GetAudioSamples' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

after I got this I did download Microsoft Visual C++ from [this link](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/) however the problem still persists. what should I do?

Comment: Did you download Visual Studio 2019?  Visual C++ 14.0 is Visual Studio 2015.  Check this page.  https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Comment: I read from somewhere that I can use any newer version. besides do I have to download a new version of VS every time I need to build something? why is that?

Comment: The version of the file you have really does want C++ 14.0 and will not accept anything else, as the message says. The `pip` developers fixed this in later versions so what you have read is also true in general, but not in this specific case. If you don't have Python 3.9 you might consider upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all the required packages installed and reboot the computer.

The package you need to install:

[image: The package you need to install]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: please post images in english

Comment: Or better yet, might you please [edit] your answer to include the required package(s) as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's requested here not to to use images for this purpose, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.